# Why `majority-min-cap` set to 5 by default for Akka Sharding?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

We in our team are currently thinking if we dare to change the default setting

```
akka.cluster.sharding.distributed-data.majority-min-cap = 5
```

Which frequently makes Akka sharding stuck on rolling update of less than 5 nodes cluster. What is the specific bad scenario that should be prevented by this value? I struggle to see how simple majority e.g. 4/5 don't work for small clusters. Why not `majority-min-cap = 2`?

UPD: just a link to the config for convenience https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-cluster-sharding/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L157

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/21618

In short, the issue above states that with small clusters there is too high of a chance that a change in cluster membership can adversely affect a "majority" decision. (I'm only quoting the GitHub issue, I haven't run any tests on actual risks.)

I suspect, however, that if you are having problems with rolling upgrades that there might be something else at issue.